# C program outputting different values with different numbers?

Tags: c++, c, comparison, type-conversion

See the program below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x = 0.1;
    if (x == 0.1)
        printf("IF");
    else if (x == 0.1f)
        printf("ELSE IF");
    else
        printf("ELSE");
}
```

And another program here

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        float x = 0.5;
        if (x == 0.5)
            printf("IF");
        else if (x == 0.5f)
            printf("ELSE IF");
        else
            printf("ELSE");
    }
```

From the both programs we expect similar results because nothing has literally changed in both changed, everything is same and also comparison terms are changed correspondingly.

BUT 2 above programs produce different results

1st Program

```
ELSE
```

2nd Program

```
IF
```

Why is this 2 programs behaving differently

Comment: You are comparing `floats`.  You should definitely have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404513/floating-point-equality-and-tolerances

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977151/what-happens-to-the-value-of-a-floating-point-number-when-its-assigned-to-a-lon/37977225#37977225

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of these two programs will vary between computers and operating systems - you are testing for *exact equality* of `floats`.

In memory, `floats` are stored as a string of bits in `binary` - i.e. 0.1 in binary (0.1b) represents 0.5 in decimal (0.5d).

Similarly,

```
Binary | Decimal
0.1    |  2^-1        = 1/2
0.01   |  2^-2        = 1/4
0.001  |  2^-3        = 1/8
0.11   |  2^-1 + 2^-2 = 3/4
```

The problem is that some decimals don't have nice floating point representations. 
    0.1d   =  0.0001100110011001100110011...
which is infinitely long.

So, 0.5 is really nice in binary

`0.5d = 0.1000000000000000...b`

but 0.1 is really nasty

`0.1d = 0.00011001100110011...`

Now depending on your compiler, it may assume that 0.1f is a `double` type, which stores more of the infinite sequence of 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011...
so it is not equal to the `float` version, which truncates the sequence much earlier.

On the other hand, 0.5f is the same regardless of how many decimal places are stored, since it has all zeroes after the first place.

The accepted way to compare `float`s or `double`s in C++ or C is to `#define` a very small number (I like to call it EPS, short for EPSILON) and replace

```
float a = 0.1f
if (a == 0.1f) {
    printf("IF\n")
} else {
    printf("ELSE\n")
}
```

with

```
#include <math.h>

#define EPS 0.0000001f

float a = 0.1f
if (abs(a - 0.1f) < EPS) {
    printf("IF\n")
} else {
    printf("ELSE\n")
}
```

Effectively, this tests if a is 'close enough' to 0.1f instead of exact equality. For 99% of applications, this approach works just fine, but for super-sensitive calculations some stranger tricks are needed that involve using `long double`, or defining a custom data type.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two data types: double,automaticly in 
`if(x=0.1)`)
(0.1 is double) and x is float. these types differ how they store the value. 0.1 is not 0.1f, it is 0.100000000001 (double) or 0.09388383(something)

Comment: some interesting https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: it is good idea to use only double or only float